# How do I get the total number of elements of a nested sequelize model?

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

please tell me how to get the total number of elements of the nested sequelize model?
It is necessary for include to return, in addition to the array of all nested models, also count (the number of all nested models)
I would be grateful for the answer

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
})

const ProductVariant = sequelize.define('product_variant', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  color: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  model: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
})

Product.hasMany(ProductVariant, { as: 'variant' })
ProductVariant.belongsTo(Product)

products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: ProductVariant,
            as: 'variant',
            limit: 4,
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
          },
        ],
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: ProductVariant,
            as: 'variant',
            attributes:[[sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('model')), 'TotalNumberOfModels']
          },
        ],
      })
```